# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element

Tags: web-services, cxf

This comes from this method

```
@WebResult(name = "logoutResponse", 
targetNamespace = "http://schemas.novell.com/2005/01/GroupWise/methods", 
partName = "logoutRes")
@WebMethod(action = "logoutRequest")
    public com.novell.schemas._2005._01.groupwise.methods.LogoutResponse 
    logoutRequest(
    @WebParam(partName = "logoutReq", name = "logoutRequest", 
    targetNamespace = "http://schemas.novell.com/2005/01/GroupWise/methods")
    com.novell.schemas._2005._01.groupwise.methods.LogoutRequest logoutReq,
    @WebParam(partName = "sessionId", name = "session", 
    targetNamespace = "http://schemas.novell.com/2005/01/GroupWise/types", 
    header = true)
    java.lang.String sessionId,
    @WebParam(partName = "gwTrace", name = "gwTrace", 
    targetNamespace = "http://schemas.novell.com/2005/01/GroupWise/types", 
    header = true)
    boolean gwTrace
    );
```

The error obtained is the following:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element 
(uri:"http://schemas.novell.com/2005/01/GroupWise/methods", local:"code"). 
Expected elements are <{http://schemas.novell.com/2005/01/GroupWise/types}info>,
<{http://schemas.novell.com/2005/01/GroupWise/types}code>,
<{http://schemas.novell.com/2005/01/GroupWise/types}description>,
<{http://schemas.novell.com/2005/01/GroupWise/types}problems>
```

I don't understand what is wrong, as the code attribute is there. Those expected elements are part of a Status object, and other response methods that use the same Status object have no problem at all

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `@XmlSchema Annotation` in `package-info.java`. Try regenerating your java classes again.

Comment: all I see is @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://schemas.novell.com/2005/01/GroupWise/methods", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED), the java classes are recompiled every time. If you read is only one method out of 50 that does not work

Comment: basically what is happening is there is some parsing error when you are unmarshalling. i got a similar exception when i was deserializing xmls; it was resolved when i added the package-info class. btw, your package-info looks fine.